# Binary file conversion in distributed manner - Spark, Flume or any other option?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, flume, asn.1

We have a scenario where there will be a continuous incoming set of binary files (ASN.1 type to be exact). We want to convert these binary files to different format, say XML or JSON, and write to a different location. I was wondering what would be the best architectural design to handle this kind of problem? I know we could use Spark cluster for CSV, JSON, parquet kind of files but I'm not sure we could use it for binary file processing, or we could use Apache Flume to move files from one place to another and even use interceptor to convert the contents.

It's ideal if we can switch the ASN.1 decoder whenever we have performance considerations without changing the underlying framework of distributed processing (ex: to use C++ based or python based or Java based decoder library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of scalability, reliability and future-proofing your solution, I'd look at [Apache NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org/) rather than Flume. You can start by developing your own ASN.1 Processor or try using [the patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6752) thats already available but not part of a released version yet.

Comment: Thank you for your direction, any reason why NiFi over flume, can you also tell me that Nifi support file conversion and can write our own conversion logic (like in Flume interceptors). Also can we use external script or executable (shell script or c executable) in the middle of the NiFi process? 
If I use the patch, should I need to build the Nifi myself instead of downloading it, again thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks @Tekz. Hopefully NiFi online docs (https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/) can satisfy your interest in greater detail. Here, I'll be brief considering that its just a comment: 1) _can you wrtie your own conversion logic_ - yes, absolutely, using Developer API; 2) _can use external scripts or executables_ - yes, certainly, using ExecuteProcess or ExecuteStreamCommand;  3) _do you need to build from source if using a patch_ - generally yes, but not necessarily in this case (ASN1 Processor) since you can tweak patch source to use it as a custom extension (see (1)),

Comment: thank you very much I'll check on how to get the patch code to use as a extension, I think you meant to use it as custom processor I believe. Any idea why the patch is not merged yet as it is over 8 months now. Anyway thank you very much for the guidance